# Github API: How to get all repositories written in a given language

Tags: github

I was able to get all github repositories tagged with a given language in JSON format with the v2 of the [github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/), but this version [has been deprecated](https://github.com/blog/1160-github-api-v2-end-of-life) last year. I can't find any way to do this with the [new v3](http://developer.github.com/v3/).

Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't tried (hence comment), but the [repository search](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) seems to have a language parameter that can be fed into it... Might that be able to be leveraged or does it require a keyword?

Comment: @Charlie. Thanks, I overlooked that. But if I understand the documentation correctly, it seems that this should work: `https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/Go?language=Go`, but it doesn't

Comment: Are you sending `application/vnd.github.preview` in the header?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I run:

`> curl https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/Go?language=Go`

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "repo",
      "username": "mattn",
      "name": "go-gtk",
      "owner": "mattn",
      "homepage": "http://mattn.github.com/go-gtk",
      "description": "Go binding for GTK",
      "language": "Go",
      "watchers": 342,
      "followers": 342,
      "forks": 67,
      "size": 416,
      "open_issues": 34,
      "score": 54.450714,
      "has_downloads": true,
      "has_issues": true,
      "has_wiki": true,
      "fork": false,
      "private": false,
      "url": "https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk",
      "created": "2009-11-26T16:58:53Z",
      "created_at": "2009-11-26T16:58:53Z",
      "pushed_at": "2013-09-02T04:29:39Z",
      "pushed": "2013-09-02T04:29:39Z"
    }
  ]
}
<TRIMMED>
```

Which seems to be the nature of the response you are looking for.

Also, on the [latest version of the API](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories#languages), you can try:

`curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.preview.text-match+json' https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:go&order=desc`

Without the media type, you'll get:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found"
}
```

But with the `-H` media type in the request, you'll get a proper response.

On Windows:

```
c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-1.8.3-preview20130601\bin\curl.exe -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.preview.text-match+json" https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:go&order=desc
```

(note the `"` instead of `'` around the header `Accept`)

Comment: That only returns top 99

Comment: It can be paginated https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#pagination