# GitHub Api: list of all repos with a given language

Tags: github, github-api

Yes, there is this question:

[Github API: How to get all repositories written in a given language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417162/github-api-how-to-get-all-repositories-written-in-a-given-language)

however the answer provided only returns 100 results.

So how can I get the list of ALL repositories for a given language,

e.g. for Mathematica

curl https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:mathematica

says there are 8000+ items that I should get, but this returns only top 30...

I have tried `since`

Comment: check https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/

Comment: @BertrandMartel works, but why has it changed from `since`? also, it is a bit frustrating that I can not request more than 100 results per page.

Comment: @BertrandMartel also I can only get the first 1000 results :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by **@Bertrand Martel** adding

```
&page=<page>&per_page=100
```

works.

You just have to request page 1 with 1 result per page to get total results, and then iterate over pages as needed.

Comment: Can this really iterate over all repos? Or is it limited to first 100 pages?

Comment: @Hieu still limited to first 100 pages

Comment: Does each pagination count as a new call to the API? I am facing the problem to overcome the limit of 30 calls per minute

Comment: @GiovanniGrano yes, you are rate limited